# Как написать правильно replace в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как записать правильно?
А то удаляет только если есть последний пример.

```
xt = x.replace(/ мин назад/g, '');
xt = x.replace(/ д назад/g, '');
xt = x.replace(/ ч назад/g, '')
```

Comment: Какая входная строка? Что хотите получить?

Comment: Вы каждый раз берёте старую строку `x`, меняете её и запихиваете в новую `xt`. При этом предыдущий вариант `xt` естественно уничтожается. Думаю во второй и третьей строках вы хотели что-то вроде `xt = xt...`

Comment: `xt = x.replace(/ ((мин)|д|ч) назад/g, '');`

Comment: @br3t, внутренние скобки лишние.

Comment: @Qwertiy осталось от варианта без наружных скобок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не плодить весьма похожие регулярки можно сделать одну "универсальную":

```
xt = x.replace(/ (мин|д|ч) назад/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) не изменяет существующую строку, а возвращает **новую**.

Вот пример, как можно выполнить несколько последовательных замен в одной строке:

```
var xt = x.replace(/ мин назад/g, '')
    .replace(/ д назад/g, '')
    .replace(/ ч назад/g, '');
```